# How to print 1 image per (paper) sheet with maximum dimensions

Tags: css, printing

With a HTML document that includes only images, how can I scale the images to fill the entire sheet?
I want the image to scale it's width/height to be as large as possible /small as necessary to fit on one paper sheet.

I started to use this for the pagebreak

```
footer {page-break-after:always;}
```

I do not know where to start for the height / width for the image?

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

html

```
<img class="printThisFull" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90">
    <img class="printThisFull" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90">
```

If you want to stretch image to full page area

```
 @media print {
     .printThisFull {
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         page-break-after:always
     }
 }
```

If you want to image to full page width keeping aspect ratio

```
 @media print {
     .printThisFull {
         width:100%;
         height:auto;
         page-break-after:always
     }
 }
```

If you want to image to full page height keeping aspect ratio

```
 @media print {
     .printThisFull {
         width:auto;
         height:100%;
         page-break-after:always
     }
 }
```

You can try this

make new html file of below code and launch it in your browser, press crt + p, and you will see it working.

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <img class="printThisFull" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90">
    <img class="printThisFull" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90">
    <style>
        @media print {
            .printThisFull {
                width:100%;
                height:auto;
                page-break-after:always
            }
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, `display: block; page-break-after: always;` helped the case